# List of Soundcloud iframe parameters?

Tags: iframe, embed, soundcloud

I'm working on a CMS, and want to let users embed Soundcloud tunes and playlists.
I'd like to avoid fiddling with the API - since it doesn't appear to be necessary: )
Instead I just piece together an iframe-src-url with the appropriate parameters.
I was unable to find an *official list* anywhere, so I've collected my own, from various posts here and elsewhere:

```
&color=FF4444  // play-button and equalizer graphic (if not &visual=true)  
&auto_play=false  // shouls be obvious  
&show_artwork=true  // show the artist-graphic on the left  
&show_comments=true  // show fans commenst under equalizer  
&show_playcount=true  // number of times played @ bottom right  
&hide_related=true  // don't force user over to Soundcloud after play  
&show_user=false  // don't show uploaders name @ top left
&show_reposts=false  // ?
&liking=fals‌​e  // dont show [Like] button  
&visual=true  // use artist-graphic for background (way cooler)  
&buying=false  // no Buy (iTunes) button  
&sharing=false  // no [Share] button  
&download=false  // no download button  
&start_track=4  // start at specific track (for lists)

And guesed : )  
&following=false (removes [Follow] when mouseover artwork)
```

What parameters am I missing?

What I really want is **Next** and **Previous** buttons for lists. Do they even exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing:

```
download=true // Show/hide download buttons
sharing=true  // Show/hide share buttons/dialogues
start_track=0 // Preselects a track in the playlist, given a number between 0 and the length of the playlist.
```

Found in the [docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#params).

It looks like `next()` and `prev()` and `skip(index)` are all [methods](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods) on the widget rather than parameters.  You can get around this by keeping an index of the current track and pass in a value to the `start_track` parameter as a way to get to the next and previous tracks.

Comment: Thank you - added 3 new to the list : )  I was afraid of that answer. The start_track trick would require the listener to never finish a track : (

Comment: @T4NK3R These are all of the public parameters.  What you're asking for doesn't exist.  I've done my best to provide a solution with the interfaces exposed.

Comment: I know, and appreciate! - but still hoping there for a secret/experimental one...

Comment: I just realized: If the iframe is tall enough (+225px) the tracks are listed under the, with titles, plays and everything = No need for next/prev buttons  :  )

Answer (score 0):

To add shuffle or next track, you can also combine the embedded player, and add buttons that trigger following soundcloud widget functions:

```js
    // Function to shuffle the SoundCloud playlist
    function shufflePlaylist() {
        // Use the SoundCloud widget API to control the player
        var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud-player'));

        // Get the total number of tracks in the playlist
        widget.getSounds(function (sounds) {
            // Generate a random index
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);

            // Play the track at the random index
            widget.skip(randomIndex);
        });
    }

    // Function to play the next track in the SoundCloud playlist
    function nextTrack() {
        // Use the SoundCloud widget API to control the player
        var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud-player'));

        // Play the next track
        widget.next();
    }
```